# Controller not returning ajax response ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to cascade the dependent State and City list from  drop-down on selecting Country.

So, I select India => Maharashtra => Cities from Maharastra should cascade.

In the Controller I am able to see city list, but same is not returns to ajax success call in jquery.

Data is viewed in controller but not going to the Ajax Success event.

View

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var noCountry = $("#Country").children("option:selected").text();

    if (noCountry != '') {

        $('#state').append("<option value='0'>Selet State</option>");
    }

    $("#Country").change(function () {


        var selkt = noCountry;

        var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").text();

        $('#state').empty();

        $('#state').append("<option value='0'>Selet State</option>");

        if (selectedCountry != '') {

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/GetStates",
                data: { selectedCountry: selectedCountry },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#state').append(new Option(item.stateName, item.stateId));
                        });
                    }
                }



            });//ajax ends



        } 



    }); //First logik ends here

    //Kountry logik starts here

    $('#cityList').append("<option value='0'>Select City</option>").text();

    $('#state').change(function () {

        var stateSelected = $('#state').children("option:selected").text();

        if (stateSelected != 'Selet State' | stateSelected != '') {

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/GetCity",
                data: { stateSelected: stateSelected },
                success: function (data)
                {

                    alert("Working")

                },
                error: function () {

                    alert("Failed")
                }


            });//2nd ajax end here


        }


    }); //2nd logik ends here

});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCity(string stateSelected)
    {

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            State state = db.States.Where(x => x.stateName == stateSelected).FirstOrDefault();

            int id = state.stateId;

            List<City> data = db.Cities.Where(x => x.stateId == id).ToList();

            ViewBag.ID = id;

            ViewBag.list = data;

            return Json(new {data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });//cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        }
    }
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated
Please help with this. Thank you

Comment: I write your controller code and second ajax function code in my system, its works !!!

Comment: Is it working for State and City , beause for me it is not as in the screenshot

Comment: @Soheil attah a snap shot from your end

Answer (score 0):

I run your code with some changes on my system and it works.

View :

```
@section scripts{
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selectedCountry = "b";

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/GetStates",
                data: { selectedCountry: selectedCountry },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data && data.data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#state').append("<option value=" + item.ID + ">" + item.Name + "</option>");
                        });
                    }
                }



            });


            $('#state').change(function () {

                var stateSelected = $('#state').children("option:selected").text();

                if (stateSelected != 'Selet State' | stateSelected != '') {

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "/Home/GetCity",
                        data: { stateSelected: stateSelected },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("working")

                            if (data && data.data.length > 0) {
                                $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
                                    $('#city').append("<option value=" + item.ID + ">" + item.Name + "</option>");
                                });
                            }

                        },
                        error: function () {

                            alert("Failed")
                        }


                    });//2nd ajax end here


                }


            }); //2nd logik ends here
            
        });
    </script>
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained exactly what changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the action

```
public JsonResult GetCity(string stateSelected)
{
  //....your code   
  return new JsonResult(data);
}
```

if you still have some problems try to add dataType to ajax

```
 ....
 data: { stateSelected: stateSelected },
 dataType: 'json', 
....
```

Comment: Thanks will try and will let u know

Comment: Hi, tried but not working.

Comment: @RiyazShaikh I post only tested code. It returns data properly. You have to explain what do you mean when you tell "not working"